# How to enable Einstein and configure it?

Tags: configuration, setup, einstein

How to enable and setup Einstein?

I checked [Salesforce Einstein Features](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/get_smart_einstein_feat) trailhead, I watched a few videos and searched articles/[topics](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143822/salesforce-einstein-what-are-the-new-features-and-what-is-their-impact) about Einstein. I found what Einstein can do but not how to enable it and configure.
Assuming that Lightning is enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Einstein is an AI on top of various cloud offerings like sales, service, marketing ,community and so on .

Some of the features are baked into platform and freely available while rest you will need to contact your AE as there are additional feature cost to it .

Example for Sales Cloud Lead Scoring and Opportunity Prediction you will need contact salesforce to enable for additional cost while if you are using community cloud most of the features like Recommending articles and topics are freely available .

Just enabling lightning wont get you access to Einstein .

Comment: Could you call Salesforce to enable this special features in a Developer Org though, only for testing and development purpose?

Comment: Not sure on that yet on plans for supporting DE orgs yet

Comment: One tip to a researchers - Einstein is not available for Europe clients O_o

Answer (score 2):

[Set Up Sales Cloud Einstein](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_sales_einstein_setup.htm) - to set up Sales Cloud Einstein, use the in-app Einstein Setup Assistant as a guide. You select who can use Einstein, enable Einstein features, and configure pages and list views so sales reps can see insights.

EDIT 1.
To enable Einstein a sales representative should be contacted. That person will tell you the price.
No preview can be enabled for your sandbox. My assumption here is that you can ask for an enabling in sandbox with not enough data to teach Einstein or with empty sandbox at all. In this case Einstein won't work in your org. But they can show you working Einstein in THEIR org, where they have sufficient amount of data and already smart Einstein.
First of all, before even thinking about Einstein check if you have sufficient amount of data to teach Einstein.

Comment: Is there anything for Developer Org?

Comment: I don't think so. To enable Einstein you need a lot of data. Maybe you can enable it in Partial Copy or Full sandboxes. But from what I experienced, Salesforce representative could make a PRESENTATION of Einstein feature on their SPECIALLY prepared org.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, the only thing Einstein can do with just lightning alone is recommend actions by searching for keywords, for example if you have cases and certain keywords are followed up with a specific action, it's supposed to recommend the most common actions for you automatically, or if you always send an e-mail to your manager after a specific keyword (example: disaster, fire, meltdown etc.) in a case it will recommend for you to draft an e-mail to your boss and may include the email content itself.

Haven't seen this in action yet since I just enabled Lightning